# Как сделать тень в Андроид как на примере?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sdk, android-layout

Как сделать тень в Андроид как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2):

В ImageView вставите ваше изображение

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">
    
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
    
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: elevation даст немного другую тень, на картинке у автора не совсем естественная, но это уже ему выбирать :)

Comment: ну пусть тогда рыскает по библиотекам вроде этой https://github.com/qhutch/ElevationImageView в поиске нужной. ))